# jqxValidator, disable auto scroll on validation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqwidget

Im having problems with the jqxValidator. When i run .jqxValidator('validate') the window scrolls to the validated input, if it contains a error. 
Is there a way to disable this function and let the scrollbar stay the way it is?

I tried the properties and functions described on there site:

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxvalidator/jquery-validator-api.htm

But with no luck.
Here is a fiddle with my problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/mGqWD/5/

```
$('#testForm').jqxValidator({
 rules: [{
     input: '#userInput',
     message: 'Username is required!',
     action: 'blur',
     rule: 'required'
 }]});

$("#jqxbutton").click(function () {
    $('#testForm').jqxValidator('validate'); 
});
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Did you check it's javascript library? It must have an option for scrolling if any validation error comes. Just comment-out that statement to avoid scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

the scroll property should not be in the rules but the in jqxValidator

```
$('#testForm').jqxValidator({
     focus: false,
     scroll: false,
     rules: [{
        input: '#userInput',
         message: 'Username is required!',
         action: 'blur',
         rule: 'required'
     }]
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

During the initialization, set scroll: false

Answer (score 0):

It's simple as hell. Just set focus attribute to false.

```
 $('#testForm').jqxValidator({
     focus: false,
     rules: [{
         input: '#userInput',
         message: 'Username is required!',
         action: 'blur',
         rule: 'required'
     }]
 });
```

Here's the updated [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mGqWD/10/)

Comment: Your fiddle still crolls to the top when validating. I found "this.scroll=true" in the library that I can set to false to stop the auto-scroll, but
then I or any colleague cant upgrade the library without remembering to change the source code every time. And I cant seem to sett the variable
from outside the library. thank you any way.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#testForm').jqxValidator('validateInput','#userInput');`

Answer (score 0):

In angular, the scroll property does not exist within its attributes but it can be defined in the...

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.myValidator.setOptions({scroll:false , focus: false, closeOnClick: false });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

> Just set scroll:false. I Hope help.

```
 $('#testForm').jqxValidator({
     focus: false,
     rules: [{
         scroll: false,
         input: '#userInput',
         message: 'Username is required!',
         action: 'blur',
         rule: 'required'
     }]
 });
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem.  If you tab out of the control, with no input, it still scrolls.